# Why does this anonymous func return the same instance of struct?

Tags: go

```
package main

import "fmt"

type fake struct {
}

func main() {
    f := func() interface{} {
        return &fake{}
    }

    one := f()
    two := f()

    fmt.Println("Are equal?: ", one == two)
    fmt.Printf("%p", one)
    fmt.Println()
    fmt.Printf("%p", two)
    fmt.Println()
}
```

(http://play.golang.org/p/wxCUUCyz98)

Why does this anonymous func return the same instance of the requested type and how can i make it return a new one on each call?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You compare two interfaces with `one == two`. Let's see what the [language specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators) has to say on the meaning of this expression:

> Interface values are comparable. Two interface values are equal if
>   they have identical dynamic types and equal dynamic values or if both
>   have value nil.
>
> Pointer values are comparable. Two pointer values are equal if they
>   point to the same variable or if both have value nil. Pointers to
>   distinct zero-size variables may or may not be equal.

In your example, both `one` and `two` are both interface values, and they have the same dynamic type (`*fake`). Their dynamic values are both pointers to a zero-sized object though, and as you can read above, equality may or may not hold in this case.

Given this, you can solve your problem by not using pointers to zero-sized structs as unique values. Perhaps use an `int` instead?

That might look like this:

```
type fake int

func main() {
    var uniq fake
    f := func() interface{} {
        uniq++
        return uniq
    }
    ...
}
```

It's not clear what you're trying to achieve, so this may or may not be a good solution for you.

Comment: Is it possible to convert the &fake{} struct to an int type, that represents the memory address for comparison reasons?

Comment: Yes, using unsafe. But if you start with two identical pointers and convert them both to ints, you're still going to get the same comparison. I'll explain in my answer what I meant.

Comment: Sorry, if i wasn't clear. I'm trying to achieve an instance comparison of 2 random structs, not 2 random integers. What i meant in the previous comment was, how to get the memory address of the struct type "fake" (or any type of struct) into an integer for memory location comparison, not use integers for comparisons to start with.

Comment: I understand what your code is doing (comparing two interfaces containing pointers to zero-sized structs), but I don't understand what you're trying to achieve by doing that. Probably there's a better way to achieve what you're trying to do if you explained your intention.

Comment: I'm trying to see, if the two objects are of the same instance. For example in Java you would compare hashcodes of objects to determine, if two objects are the same instance or not.

Comment: The values are zero-sized so aren't stored in memory. The language specification does not guarantee that pointers to two different "instances" of zero-sized objects are different. In Java, there's no concept of a zero-sized object: all objects are at least 8 bytes (or 16 bytes on a 64bit machine) large.

Comment: Uhm ok, wasn't aware of that. So i can assume the comparisons produce valid results, when the struct is not empty.

Answer (score 1):

The final paragraph of the language spec:

> A struct or array type has size zero if it contains no fields (or
>   elements, respectively) that have a size greater than zero. Two
>   distinct zero-size variables may have the same address in memory.

http://golang.org/ref/spec#Size_and_alignment_guarantees

So as noted in the accepted answer, you will see what you expect if you use a non-empty struct.